# Recover unaltered java from APK

Tags: java, android, apk

I recently lost my android game code. When I tried to retrieve it from APK in my test device, I was able to recover all assets, xml and few java files - less complex ones (using dex2java converter). However original code of the more complex java files (like renderer) couldnt be recovered properly. Lots of modifications had been made to the code (like additional while, break, continue, labels).
Please suggest how the actual JAVA code(unaltered) can be recovered from the APK.
Thanks

Comment: _Please suggest how the actual JAVA code(unaltered) can be recovered from the APK_ Simple answer: it can't.

Comment: It can't; can you imagine?! I can sympathize, but backups and source control are *mandatory*.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, you can right-click on your project name and select `Restore from Local History`. Anyway, this teaches you to always have some backup of your project/s (**every now and then**, during the day, I **zip the project folder** with a name which includes the project name and the date, plus a progressive number)

Comment: How did you lose your code? Perhaps there is some other way to recover it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that it cannot.

Source code is not included into the compiled version.  The compiled classes only contain JVM instructions.  From these instructions, you can often reconstruct the logic, but rarely if ever the original source.

Comment: Thanks for the quick one; If that is the case, will that java code be logically accurate? (can it still use the java code for my game?)

Comment: Yes, it's logically the same code as the Java you started with.  It just has all the comments removed, and the variable names have been lost.